# How to access Scrapy httpcache middleware data directly

Tags: scrapy

How could I access the httpcache middleware from scrapy directly?

Something like such in pseudo code

```
URL = 'http://scrapedsite.com/category1/item1'
print retrieveRawHtml(URL)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
url = 'http://scrapedsite.com/category1/item1'
body = '<html>hello</html>'
response = HtmlResponse(url, body=body)
open_in_browser(response)
```

or from your callback:

```
def parse_cb(self, response):
    from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
    open_in_browser(response)
```

If caching is turned on it will pull from cache.

Comment: "If caching is turned on it will pull from cache.", interesting. Can you draw some lines on how to do that? Thank you.

Comment: see [HTTPCACHE_ENABLED](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-enabled) setting